# Why doesn't set cookie work with angular and service workers from external API

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, setcookie, angular-service-worker

I created an application with angular 8 and it works just fine. App is not hosted on the same domain like the API.

When I call API to login or register it returns Set-Cookie value, and then that value is used for every request to make it authorized.

PROBLEM: Once i installed service workers calls to remote API don't work, instead of Cookie being stored there is nothing.

I am new to service workers.

Comment: can you please post your same code here

Comment: Just off the top of my head.
A Cookie would be added as part of the request header. For example, an authentication token.
You may not have access to the cookie header for an external domain. Its whole CORS, no-cors opaque request thing.
I don't the perfect answer. But make sure you have CORS headers setup on the API server and make sure the mode on your fetch request is 'cors'. You can then cache the GET responses from the API. However I think you may be better off persisting the data in IndexedDB. That is how I deal with API data. It all depends on your application though.